# error while loading shared libraries: libXinerama.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu

im getting this error when trying to run

```
vmware-vcenter-converter
```

/usr/lib/vmware-vcenter-converter-standalone/converter-gui: error while loading shared libraries: libXinerama.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

> locate libXinerama

result as following

```
 /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libXinerama.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libXinerama.so.1/libXinerama.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-installer/2.1.0/lib/lib/libXinerama.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-installer/2.1.0/lib/lib/libXinerama.so.1/libXinerama.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1.0.0
```

my box  arch : 
Ubuntu 13

```
uname -a
 3.11.0-14-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 17:04:55 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

i was trying to install different package to fix this issue , no luck

Any tips to fix missing shared libs

Comment: Shouldn't you try to locate libXinerama.so.1 instead of libXcursor.so.1?

Comment: its type i copied wrong ouput , i was trying  libXinerama already but no luck

Comment: Try installing the "libxinerama1" package with `sudo apt-get install libxinerama1`.

Comment: already did , libxinerama1 is already the newest version.

Comment: Could it be that you're using the 32-bit version of VMware even though you're on a 64-bit Ubuntu? If yes, then `apt-get install libxinerama1:i386` and try again. Or install the 64-bit version of VMware instead.

Comment: What's the output of `ldd /usr/lib/vmware-vcenter-converter-standalone/converter-gui` ?

Comment: @Lawrence : here is out put : its too long so i pasted here  http://pastebin.com/UVXg70fG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the output of ldd, it would seem that `converter-gui` is running on 32-bit libs.
You will need to install the 32bit version of all the libs missing from the ldd output

```
libvmomi.so.1.2 => not found
libvmacore.so.1.2 => not found
libtypes.so => not found
libXinerama.so.1 => not found
libexpat.so.0 => not found
libConverterWizard.so => not found
libconverterLogicTypes.so => not found
libconverterTypes.so => not found
```

Which should just involve a `apt-get install` for xinerama and expat
`apt-get install libxinerama1:i386` and `apt-get install libexpat1:i386`

If you have the rest of the missing libs on the system already, you'll need to point the program to the location where the libs are located with `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/i386/vm/libs:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: If you are on OpenSUSE, the package name is libXinerama-32bit

Answer (score 3):

Just do

```
apt install libxinerama1
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like libXinerama.so.1 is in your system, but not in the folder vmware is looking for it. Have you tried a link?

```
    ln /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 /usr/lib/vmware-vcenter-converter-standalone/libXinerama.so.1
```

However, you can give us more info doing this:

```
    ls -ld /usr/ /usr/lib/ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
    ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1
```

Comment: i did , and ouput as :  ln /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 /usr/lib/vmware-vcenter-converter-standalone/converter-gui/libXinerama.so.1
ln: accessing ‘/usr/lib/vmware-vcenter-converter-standalone/converter-gui/libXinerama.so.1’: Not a directory

Comment: yeah, sorry, I mean ln /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 /usr/lib/vmware-vcenter-converter-standalone/libXinerama.so.1

Comment: you can give us more info doing this `ls -ld /usr/ /usr/lib/ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`

Comment: no luck didnot work

Comment: drwxr-xr-x  10 root root  4096 Oct 16 22:58 /usr/
drwxr-xr-x 242 root root 36864 Dec 15 16:02 /usr/lib/
drwxr-xr-x 104 root root 69632 Dec 15 16:02 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

Comment: directories' permissions are ok. Check the library ones with `ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1`

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx 2 root root 20 Oct 20 16:08 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 -> libXinerama.so.1.0.0

Comment: as your script runs ok if you invoke it, i think `chown YOURUSERNAME filebot.sh` and `chmod u+s,a+x filebot.sh` worth a try.